# No puedo ingresar información a base de datos con jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, html, html5, datatables

tengo un formulario HTML con seis inputs y un datatable jQuery de la siguiente manera

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="idPais" required>
    <input type="text" id="idNombres" required>
    <input type="text" id="idTelefono" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="idCorreo" required>
    <input type="text" id="idDUI" required>
    <input type="text" id="idISSS" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="button" id="Guardar" value="Guardar">Guardar Registro</button>
</div>

    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-condensed" id="myTable" style="width:100%; margin:0 auto;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Pais</th>
                    <th>Nombres</th>
                    <th>Telefono</th>
                    <th>Correo</th>
                    <th>DUI</th>
                    <th>NIT</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
```

la función con la que cargo el datatable jQuery es la siguiente:

```
function CargarTabla() {

                $('#myTable').DataTable({
                    destroy: true,
                    searching: false,
                    paging: true,
                    responsive: true,
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "/home/loaddata",
                        "type": "GET",
                        "datatype": "json"
                    },
                    "columns": [
                            { "data": "pais", "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false },
                            { "data": "nombres", "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false },
                            { "data": "telefono", "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false },
                            { "data": "correo", "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false },
                            { "data": "dui", "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false },
                            { "data": "nit", "autoWidth": true, "orderable": false },
                            //{ "defaultContent": "<button>editar</button>" }
                    { "defaultContent": " <a href='#' id='select'>Modificar</a>  "}
                    ],
                    "oLanguage": {
                        "sEmptyTable": "No hay registros disponibles",
                        "sInfo": "Hay _TOTAL_ registros. Mostrando de (_START_ a _END_)",
                        "sLoadingRecords": "Por favor espera - Cargando...",
                        "sSearch": "Filtro:",
                        "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_",
                        "oPaginate": {
                            "sLast": "Última página",
                            "sFirst": "Primera",
                            "sNext": "Siguiente",
                            "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

y el controlador MVC que lo carga es este:

```
 public ActionResult loaddata()
        {
           string conexion= ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnn"].ConnectionString.ToString();

            List<Ejemplo> datos = new List<Ejemplo>();
            SqlConnection sql= new SqlConnection(conexion);
            SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection=sql;
            cmd.CommandText="select * from datatable";
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            var reader= cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows){
                while (reader.Read())
    {
        Ejemplo data = new Ejemplo();
                data.pais= reader["pais"].ToString();
                data.nombres= reader["nombres"].ToString();
                data.telefono = reader["telefono"].ToString();
                data.correo= reader["correo"].ToString();
                data.dui= reader["dui"].ToString();
                data.nit= reader["nit"].ToString();

                datos.Add(data);     
    }}
                return Json(new { data = datos }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

he probado cargar el datatable y funciona bien, ahora mi consulta es esta: yo quiero agregar la información que el usuario especifique en el formulario (los seis inputs HTML) en la tabla datatable que es la misma desde donde cargo el datatable jQuery y que es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo quiero hacer utilizando $.ajax() pero nunca logro ingresar los datos de hehcho en mi funcion siempre me muestra el mensaje de error especificado en `error: function (xhr, status)` , les muestro mi función en jQuery

```
$("#Guardar").click(function () {

                var Pais = $('#idPais').val();
                var Nombres = $('#idNombres').val();
                var Telefono = $('#idTelefono').val();
                var Correo = $('#idCorreo').val();
                var DUI = $('#idDUI').val();
                var NIT = $('#idISSS').val();

                if (Pais != "" && Nombres != "" && Telefono != "" && Correo != "" && DUI != "" && NIT != "") {

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",  
                        url: "Home/PruebaHTML",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: "{pais:'" + Pais + "', nombres:'" + Nombres + "', telefono:'" + Telefono + "', correo:'" + Correo + "', dui:'" + DUI + "', nit:'" + NIT + "'}",
                        //data: { pais: Pais, nombres: Nombres, telefono: Telefono, correo: Correo, dui: DUI, nit: NIT },
                        beforeSend: function () {
                            $("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.respuesta == "ok")
                                CargarTabla();
                            else {
                                alert(data.respuesta);
                            }

                        },
                        error: function (xhr, status) {

                            console.log(xhr);
                            console.log(status);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    alert('No hay datos !!! ');
                }
            });
```

y el controlador MVC al que mando la petición de ingresar la informacion

```
  [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult PruebaHTML(string pais, string nombres, string telefono, string correo, string dui, string nit)
        {
             RespuestaJSON datos = new RespuestaJSON();

            string conexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnn"].ConnectionString.ToString();
            SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(conexion);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = sql;
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into datatable values (@pais, @nombres, @telefono, @correo, @dui, @nit)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pais", pais);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombres", nombres);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefono", telefono);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@correo", correo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dui", dui);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nit", nit);

            try
            {
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (result == 1)
                {
                    datos.respuesta = "ok";
                    datos.accion = "alguna informacion...";
                }
                else
                {
                    datos.respuesta = "ok";
                    datos.accion = "alguna informacion...";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }       
            return Json(datos , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

les pido puedan ayudarme e indicarme que estoy haciendo mal, talvez el envio de los datos pues al parecer no recibo nada, por cierto devuelvo una clase llamada datos del tipo RespuestaJSON con (de momento) dos propiedades

```
public class RespuestaJSON
    {
        public string respuesta { get; set; }
        public string accion { get; set; }
    }
```

al colocar

```
 error: function (xhr, status) {
                                alert(xhr + status);
                            }
```

obtengo
 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y con console.log obtengo esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y he agregado la libreria jQuery

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

error: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, [edit] tu pregunta agregando el resultado de `function (xhr, status)`; para ello coloca: `console.log(xhr); console.log(status);`.

Comment: listo, solamente que utilice alert() y muestro el resultado al final de la pregunta

Comment: Pablo, usa por favor `console.log()` ya que la alerta no te mostrará el contenido de ese objeto/error.

Comment: Listo, es eso lo que necesita? por cierto cambie la funcion $.ajax() para que mande strings en lugar de un objeto e igualmente cambie el controlador PruebaHtml para que reciba string y guarde estos en la base de datos pero aun no logro ingresarlos

Comment: Pablo, ok, ahora puedes ver claramente el error: `JQuery no está definido`, soluciona primero ese error por favor.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave listo mauricio, la he agregado tal como muestro en la figura pero aun obtengo el error que muestro al final

Comment: de hecho veo que el problema parece ser que no encuentra el recurso, pero he especificado bien la url del controlador al que mando la informacion

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55991/discussion-between-mauricio-arias-olave-and-pablo-tobar).

Answer (score 0):

Ojo aquí:

```
url: "Home/PruebaHTML",
```

Reemplaza por:

```
url: "/PruebaHTML",
```

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/35161)

Comment: tienes razón, vi mal la url, acabo de actualizarla :D

Comment: Dura lex, sed lex

Answer (score 0):

El error que te devuelve es el 404 Not Found, lo que significa que no estas enviando la información correctamente al servidor, veo que tienes localhost:2281/Home/Home/PruebaHtml....

¿Es la ruta exacta en donde se encuentra su acción?

Comment: Jorge, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
**[cómo escribo una buena respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**. Una vez que tengas 50 puntos de reputación podrás [hacer comentarios](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). [Tu comentario se discutió previamente en el chat de esta pregunta](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55991/discussion-between-mauricio-arias-olave-and-pablo-tobar).

Comment: @jorge Alonso no Jorge, la dirección es Home=controller y PruebaHtml la acción, no entiendo porque me manda a Home/Hone/PruebaHtml, si te fijas en la url especifico bien Hone/PruebaHtml